# Replication with AWS ElastiCache (Memcached)

Tags: memcached, amazon-elasticache

I am using AWS ElastiCache Cluster (memcached) with multiple nodes. It seems that data is not replicated between nodes. When requesting data from the ElasticCache cluster endpoint, sometimes data from an earlier write is returned, but sometimes it picks a different node to read from and the data cannot be found.

Is there any practical way to replicate data between nodes with ElastiCache (Memcached)? (I would rather avoid a complex solution which I need to manage myself as this defeats the purpose of using a managed service like ElastiCache)

I have been tasked with migrating a legacy on-prem application to AWS, the previous server configuration is not available to me.

An alternative approach I was considering was ensuring that the same EC2 instances always hits the same node, however user session data is also been stored in memcached and these is no guarantee the users subsequent requests will be fulfilled by the same EC2 instance (using ALB).

Answer (score 3):

Memcached does not natively support replication. There are clients that implement replication by sending set requests to multiple endpoints.

Generally, this is not a problem since virtually all Memcached clients use hashing to select a specific endpoint for a key. This means a Memcached client does its own load balancing and you should never use a load balancer to select the Memcached endpoint. However, sometimes (e.g., due to a short network blip) the client can still choose a different endpoint for a key resulting in inconsistencies.

If you want a consistent, managed Memcache you could use a service like [MemCachier](https://www.memcachier.com/) (full disclosure, I currently work for MemCachier). Any MemCachier plan with multiple endpoints is always consistent, i.e., every endpoint *always* has the same view of your cache.